# track the movement of eyeballs of the user in iphone

Tags: xcode, core-image, face-detection, quartz-core

I am developing an application where I need to track the movement of eyeballs of the user i.e. whether the user is looking at the top or bottom of an iPhone. I have used FaceDetection in my earlier projects but in that only the eyes were detected not the movement of eyes.

Is there any API or any Framework which could detect the motion of eyeballs?? 
Any help would be great.